# Read is cancelled before stream is disposed, but still throws an exception

Tags: c#, objectdisposedexception, cancellation-token

I am currently getting an 'ObjectDisposed' exception, and I'm not sure how to resolve it. I have made sure I am checking that the stream is not closed before I begin the read operation:

```
token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
int amount = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, offset, buffer.Length - offset, token);
```

*Before* I close the stream, I cancel any pending reads:

```
tokenSource.Cancel();
stream.Close();
```

However, I am still getting the below exception:

> Cannot access a disposed object.
>   Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'.

This is spurious, so it appears to be a race condition, but it happens frequently enough for me to reproduce it. There seems to be three possibilities:

- `CancellationTokenSource` is not atomic (A quick google did not answer this)
- `NetworkStream` gives being disposed higher priority than being cancelled
- Some other reason that I am missing

How can I handle this more gracefully? Keep in mind the following restrictions I'm currently working with:

- The stream is being used in a long-lived wrapper class, which may not be in a `using` block
- The stream is from a socket wrapped by a `NetworkStream`
- The cancellation token is made from a linked token source

Comment: Show your whole block of code so we can assess this issue better

Comment: IIRC cancelling of a stream read isn't actually implemented. I might be wrong. Searching for evidence...

Comment: Yes.. I remember correctly. Read (and weep): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131434/cancel-networkstream-readasync-using-tcplistener

Comment: An interesting article for you: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/10/05/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations/

Comment: Oh damn. Thanks @spender, I never would have found that otherwise. So I guess I need to catch ObjectDisposedException, and check the cancellation token there

Comment: IKR? The fake cancellation is particularly irksome to me. Toub's article that I posted above looks like another option...