# ReadAsync on a NetworkStream appears to be using all my CPU

Tags: c#, asynchronous, profiling, networkstream

I have the following method, which reads and deserializes packets from a `NetworkStream` asynchronously. Everything works, but CPU profiling shows that the very last line, in which I am awaiting an asynchronous read, is where the majority of my CPU usage comes from.

Have I implemented this badly/inefficiently, or is there something inherently wrong with the `NetworkStream`'s async implementation?

```
public async Task<Packet> ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    while (true)
    {
        // Read through the available bytes until we find the start of a packet
        while (start < length && buffer[start] != Packet.STX)
            start++;

        // Align the packet (and all successive bytes) with the beginning of the buffer
        if (start > 0)
        {
            if (start < length)
                Array.Copy(buffer, start, buffer, 0, length - start);

            length -= start;
            start = 0;
        }

        // Read through the available bytes until we find the end of the packet
        while (end < length && buffer[end] != Packet.ETX)
            end++;

        // If we have a whole packet in the buffer, deserialize and return it
        if (end < length)
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[end + 1];
            Array.Copy(buffer, data, end + 1);
            byte[] decoded = null;
            Packet packet = null;

            try
            {
                decoded = Packet.Decode(data);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new IOException("Could not decode packet", ex);
            }

            if (decoded != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    packet = Packet.Deserialize(decoded);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new IOException("Could not deserialize packet", ex);
                }
            }

            Array.Copy(buffer, end + 1, buffer, 0, length - (end + 1));
            length -= end + 1;
            end = 0;

            if (packet != null)
                return packet;
        }

        // If we read all available bytes while looking for the end of a packet
        if (end == length)
        {
            if (length == buffer.Length)
                throw new InsufficientMemoryException();

            length += await Stream.ReadAsync(buffer, length, buffer.Length - length, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: CPU profiling results]

Comment: I'm going to guess "it's not the final postulate".

Comment: ReadAsync has to make the system calls to read the stream in to the buffer.  The rest of the code doesn't seem to be doing a lot.

Comment: this is odd because reading from a network resources generally means a lot of waiting around for the CPU

Comment: Yes, that's exactly why I made it an async method. Stepping into the function shows that the majority of time spent is in `mscorlib.ni.dll`, but I don't really know what that means

Comment: what happens to the numbers if you perform a synchronous read?

Comment: or you can try a beginread/endread approach maybe?

Comment: I will try synchronous first, I would say ReadAsync is just a wrapper for BeginRead/EndRead. Deploying takes about 10 minutes, I''l let you know how it goes

Comment: Does the profiling recognize that an async method not returning for some seconds is not using that time span for itself?

Comment: The equivalent synchronous implementation has the same performance. @phi1010 I'm not sure, this is running in an Azure worker role, and I'm using the default profiling methods in Visual Studio.

Comment: I thought it would be the same. AFAIK those cpu numbers are percentage relative to the method. Apart from the Read the rest of your method is doing very little so the Read dominates

Comment: Overall, the top three methods are: something in `mscorlib.ni.dll` (70%) which is called by `MoveNext()`, then `MoveNext()` (25%) for the read method, and then `ReadAsync()` (15%).

Comment: The real question is what does something like Task Manager say about the CPU while all this is going on. I can assure you, there is nothing wrong with the .NET implementation of `NetworkStream`. There is also nothing in your post that supports the claim that literally _"all your CPU"_ is being used. Without details like a [mcve] and information about what profiler you're using and (if applicable) what profiling mode you're using (e.g. sampling or instrumented), it's not even possible to reproduce your claim, never mind explain it.

Comment: I have a typo in the percentages above, they add up to 110% - it's supposed to be 60% not 70%. I rounded and messed that up, apologies. Azure monitoring shows between 90 and 100% usage of an extra small worker role, when I only have 6 active connections (that's what led me to investigate). I'm using _CPU sampling_, is there a more appropriate profiling method I should be using for async methods like this?

Comment: As to your claim "there is nothing wrong with the .NET implementation of `NetworkStream`", what about [the fact that you can't cancel an async read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131434/cancel-networkstream-readasync-using-tcplistener)?

Comment: Incase someone have the same issue, the solution is, you should shutdown the connection if the returned byte is zero. When zero is returned mean the other side of the socket already drop off, the system is processing  a stream which indefinitely return zero and causing the CPU to hike up,

Comment: I had a similar problem and I can confirm @ragk answer was the solution. I simply forgot to test for a return of zero bytes which means the other end of the socket is closed. Now, due to the continuous read loop, it ties down cpu resources to the quick read responses that keeps returning zero bytes. This also explains why the issue was alleviated when Andrew Williamson set a delay at the read. The best solution which worked for me is to simply test for a return of zero bytes immediately after Stream.ReadAsync's return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the code to sleep between each call to `ReadAsync`, for roughly the amount of time the last read took:

```
var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
var iteration = 0;

while (true)
{
    // ...
    var delay = stopwatch.Elapsed;
    stopwatch.Restart();

    if (iteration % 10 != 0)
        await Task.Delay(delay);

    length += await Stream.ReadAsync(buffer, length, buffer.Length - length, cancellationToken);
    stopwatch.Stop();
    iteration += 1;
}
```

This has drastically dropped the CPU usage. This is definitely a work-around, as it does not address the issue, but it works. I would love to hear anyone else's answers or opinions on this issue.

Comment: I have the same problem as you describe. Have not been able to figure it out other than have a Sleep or Delay. I wish there was a better solution out there but I guess this will have to do.

Comment: Why do you have the delay go for as long as the read took? I think a simple 10ms would suffice, I think.

Comment: Our clients tend to send a request once every minute or so, and each request fits within one TCP packet. I think I would still be seeing high CPU usage if I have a few thousand connections calling Task.Delay every 10 milliseconds, _I think_. I basically stopped implementing once I was satisfied with the performance, so there is probably room for improvement but we don't need it yet.

Comment: While this might alleviate your problem at the moment, it might cause more harm when implemented in a Single Core CPU system. (1-core systems are common when you 're on a budget VPS). The reason why calling sleep on a thread is bad is that threads are usually limited on single core systems and thus are being pooled. Once all available threads are on sleep, you immediately run into thread starvation issues. Please look at ragk's answer above, I'm sure you must have forgotten to test for return of zero bytes from ReadAsync.

Comment: @MustaphaOthman `Task.Delay` does not block the underlying thread, it yields it. I was very intentional in my implementation to make sure all the calls were asynchronous where possible

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson yes, you are absolutely right. I only read your comment that said "sleep sleep between each call" and assumed you actually called thread.sleep in your code. Yes, I see your code actually releases the thread. However, you'll still gain a lot more performance if you simply test for zero bytes and ditch the delay.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, the solution was to ensure that the int32 returned by Stream.ReadAsync() method is not a 0 (zero). If it is, simply terminate the connection as the socket has been closed on the other end.

Kindly Read the comments on the question. Someone with username Ragk provided what I consider the solution. I confirmed this coz I had a similar problem and solved it by doing exactly this. I am posting this as an answer here to help others that might encounter similar problems and might not read through all comments.

Comment: This is a six year old question so I'm not able to test this theory, but I can see in the code snippet I posted originally there is no check for a zero return so this is likely the issue